# Snowflake replace Not IN query with Not Exist or Left join does not give same count

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to replace not in query with not exist, However it is not giving the correct count.

Current Query

```
Select count(*)
from employee where
employee.city not in(
Select distinct d.city from
department d, allocation a
where d.id = a.id)
```

The count it is giving is 348988

Now I need to replace it with exist or left join

```
Select count(*)
from employee where not exists
(Select 1
from
department d, allocation a
where d.id = a.id and d.city = employee.city);
```

The count is 410991.. Even doing the left join is giving me the same number.

Please note: we need to replace "not in" Since there is more join after "not in" and snowflake is throwing error - snowflake unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated. which can be resolved by using not exists

Comment: This might be related to NULL values in your subquery. I know from before that if your subquery contains a NULL value, the NOT IN usually returns 0 rows. Perhaps the behaviour has changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(*)
from employee where
employee.city not in(
Select distinct d.city from
department d, allocation a
where d.id = a.id)
```

a NOT IN, is the same LEFT JOIN x WHERE x.y IS NUL

```
Select count(*)
from employee as e
left join (
    Select distinct d.city 
    from department as d
    join allocation as a
        on d.id = a.id
) as b
    on b.city = e.city
where b.city is null
```

and in fact the DISTINCT can be expensive, and ignored as we are take the join fail thus it should be faster to:

```
Select count(*)
from employee as e
left join (
    Select d.city 
    from department as d
    join allocation as a
        on d.id = a.id
) as b
    on b.city = e.city
where b.city is null
```

Comment: I did the exact same thing, The left join and not exists are giving the same number. However NOT In count is less than both..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Dean heather it has something to do with NULL variable.

below is the modified query with not exist where the count matches with NOT IN

```
Select count(*)
from employee where not exists
(Select 1
from
department d, allocation a
where d.id = a.id and d.city = employee.city)
and employee.city is not NULL;
```

So basically I had to eliminate all the NULL city from primary table .

Although the count is perfectly matching I am now curious if NOT IN was doing the correct job.

Comment: So I think with NOT IN, it does not equate NULL with NULL, stops when it encounters NULL values and gives back nothing. My previous experience with this was using IN and as the subquery contained NULL, it would return 0 rows as technically there was nothing in the subquery to equate to. My thinking then is that NOT EXISTS does equate these or similar, hence the different result or as I previously mentioned, perhaps the behaviour has changed and it will return all values before the NULL, rather than just stop

Comment: More info here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Zero-Rows-in-Output-with-the-presence-of-the-Not-In-Operator-in-Where-Clause